# Context broker is not started: "su: user orion does not exist"

Tags: fiware-orion, fiware

I'm trying to deploy contextBroker using the command /etc/init.d/contextBroker and I get the following error:

```
Starting...
contextBroker is stopped
Starting contextBroker...                         su: user orion does not exist
cat: /var/log/contextBroker/contextBroker.pid: No such file or directory
pidfile not found                                          [FAILED]
```

Using the following command I can start contextBroker:

> /usr/bin/contextBroker -port 10026 -logDir /var/log/contextBroker
>   -pidpath /var/log/contextBroker/contextBroker.pid -dbhost localhost -db orion

Which could be the cause of the problem?

Answer (score 1):

There was a bug in the Orion RPM fixed in 0.16.0 that causes the removal of the "orion" user when updating the RPM package. The "orion" user is the one used by default by the /etc/init.d/contextBroker script, thus causing the error message `su: user orion does not exist`.

Note that although the bug has been fixed in 0.16.0, updating from 0.15.0 (for instance) to 0.16.0 will be problematic, as the version being updated (0.15.0) is still "buggy". Updating from 0.16.0 to any newer version (e.g. upcoming 0.17.0) should work without problem.

Fortunatelly, the problem has an easy solution: instead of updating the package, remove it and install again, typically with:

```
yum remove contextBroker
yum install contextBroker
```